# How to make stock.move in Picking know about packages from Sale Order?

Tags: odoo, odoo-14

I am using Odoo version 14 Community Edition.

I would like to make each picking transfer capable of knowing the packages from Sale Order Line. Right now, I do not see any relationship from `Operation` tab (in picking) to the packages of the products selected from its Sale Order Line.

I have been trying to customize `stock.move` module to add a package field, but it does not know which lines in here come from which lines in sale order, and same product from different lines are merge into one line in picking too.

How to achieve such task?

Comment: Seems like it's something to build from scratch and integrate it at all the places that needs to be touched in order to get it done